# Redirect where no profile data in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Controller

```
function view_profil(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('idtabelX');
    $profil[''] = $this->class_model->function_model($id);
    $this->load->view('view_profil', $profil);
}
```

Model

```
function function_model($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tabelA a');
    $this->db->join('tabelB b','b.idtabelB=a.ididtabelB');
    $this->db->join('tabelC c','c.idtabelC=a.idtabelC');

    $this->db->where('idtabelX', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

If the profile is clicked, it will show the data user profile stored in database, but if the user does not have the data profile in  database, I want to redirect the user to a insert page to populate the profile data.

Thank you very much for help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller -

```
    function view_profil(){
        $id = $this->session->userdata('idtabelX');
        $profil[''] = $this->class_model->function_model($id);

        //add this bit of code
        if($profil[''] == NULL)
        {
            redirect('your_controller/your_add_method');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('view_profil', $profil);
        }
    }
```

You need to use the `redirect()` function and pass the url of your controller method for insertion as parameters.

Comment: Okay, I am very grateful you have helped me. StackOverflow have very important role as a medium to learn and ask questions about programming.